# Upgrading React version and its dependencies by reading package.json

Tags: reactjs, dependencies, upgrade

I have an existing project, which has `react@15` and all its dependencies according to that. But now I have to upgrade to `react@16` along with it's dependencies. Now, the problem is - there are a lot of dependencies and it is very time consuming to identify version of each dependency.

So, I was wondering if there was a way where I could upgrade the versions of React and its dependencies mentioned in `package.json`, without manually modifying the `package.json` file.

Comment: You might just run `yarn upgrade` which will upgrade all your packages to the latest version

Comment: `yarn upgrade` doesn't update a major version. It will upgrade from 15 to 15.6 something but not to 16.0 for that you should use `yarn upgrade --latest`

Answer (score 144):

**Using npm**

Latest version *while still respecting the semver* in your package.json: `npm update <package-name>`.
So, if your package.json says `"react": "^15.0.0"` and you run `npm update react` your package.json will now say `"react": "^15.6.2"` (the currently latest version of react 15).

But since you want to go from react 15 to react 16, that won't do.
Latest version regardless of your semver: `npm install --save react@latest`.

If you want a specific version, you run `npm install --save react@<version>` e.g. `npm install --save react@16.0.0`.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

**Using yarn**

Latest version *while still respecting the semver* in your package.json: `yarn upgrade react`.

Latest version regardless of your semver: `yarn upgrade react@latest`.

https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/upgrade/

Comment: Thank you works perfectly, npm install react@latest react-dom@latest next@latest

Answer (score 48):

if you want to update your react and react-dom version in your existing react step then run this command I hope You get the latest version of react and react-dom.

Thanks

```
npm install react@latest react-dom@latest
```

Comment: +1. Updating only one of the two - `ract-dom` and `ract` - can lead to dependency conflicts ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66801463/6367213)).

Answer (score 22):

I found a nice [article here](https://flaviocopes.com/update-npm-dependencies/).

All we need to do (for npm, globally) is:

```
sudo npm install -g npm-check-updates
```

Then run it like below:

```
ncu -u
```

It will show you all dependencies (upgraded) nicely like below:

```
Upgrading /home/ajay/Documents/react-beast/package.json
[====================] 7/7 100%

 @testing-library/user-event  ^11.4.2  →  ^13.0.16     
 react                        ^17.0.1  →   ^17.0.2     
 react-dom                    ^17.0.1  →   ^17.0.2     
 react-scripts                  4.0.1  →     4.0.3     
 web-vitals                    ^1.1.0  →    ^1.1.1
```

Try running `ncu -u` again immediately after above and you will a message like this:

```
Upgrading /home/ajay/Documents/react-beast/package.json
[====================] 7/7 100%

All dependencies match the latest package versions :)
```

Do a `npm install` after that and you should have all the latest versions for all your dependencies for your project.

To me this was the nicest and cleanest solution (well - in most cases) if we need to keep our (npm/React) project - latest and greatest - rather than wasting time on manually updating the versions.

Answer (score 15):

I highly recommend using [yarn upgrade-interactive](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/upgrade-interactive) to update React, or any Node project for that matter. It lists your packages, current version, the latest version, an indication of a Minor, Major, or Patch update compared to what you have, plus a link to the respective project.

You run it with `yarn upgrade-interactive --latest`, check out release notes if you want, go down the list with your arrow keys, choose which packages you want to upgrade by selecting with the space bar, and hit `Enter` to complete.

[Npm-upgrade](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-upgrade) is ok but not as slick.

Comment: Super interesting this option, didn't know that.. thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Some packages are interdependent and are to be used with the same versions of each other... for example recently had a problem with npm react@16.5.2 and react-dom@16.5.2. I wanted to use a hook but could not so I ran:

```
npm update react@latest react-dom@latest
```

this did not work... went into some of the react.js blogs/documentation and found that these particular packages are interdependent and the versions must be the same. To update these:

```
npm uninstall react
npm uninstall react-dom

npm install react@^16.8.0 react-dom@^16.8.0
```

And everything worked just fine. Look for stable releases. Read the documentation.
https://reactjs.org/blog/2019/02/06/react-v16.8.0.html
https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html

Comment: `npm update react@latest react-dom@latest` didn't work for me either but `npm install react@latest react-dom@latest` did the trick.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, you can use Yarn or NPM to edit your package.json.

`yarn upgrade [package | package@tag | package@version | @scope/]... [--ignore-engines] [--pattern]`

Something like:

`yarn upgrade react@^16.0.0`

Then I'd see what warns or errors out and then run `yarn upgrade [package]`. No need to edit the file manually. Can do everything from the CLI.

Or just run `yarn upgrade` to update all packages to latest, probably a bad idea for a large project. APIs may change, things may break.

Alternatively, with NPM run `npm outdated` to see what packages will be affected. Then

`npm update`

https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/upgrade/

https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/updating-local-packages

Answer (score 6):

If you want to update react use `npx update react` on the terminal.

Comment: Error: Cannot find generator: "react"

Answer (score 6):

If you want to update any specific version from the package.json you can update the version of the package by doing ==>

**yarn add package-name@version-number**

### ***or***

**npm install --save package-name@version-number**

If you want to update all packages to the latest version you can run command ==>

**npm audit fix --force**

Answer (score 2):

you can update all of the dependencies to their latest version by 
`npm update`

Answer (score 2):

You can just use this command
`npm install -g create-react-app`
if you don't have root user permissions then use this with
`sudo npm install -g create-react-app`

Answer (score 1):

#### ️ with NPM

```
npm install react@latest react-dom@latest
```

#### ️ only if you use TypeScript

```
npm install --save-dev @types/react@latest @types/react-dom@latest
```

#### ------------------------------

#### ️ with YARN

```
yarn add react@latest react-dom@latest
```

#### ️ only if you use TypeScript

```
yarn add @types/react@latest @types/react-dom@latest --dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to update react `npm install --save react@16.12.0` 
Don't forget to change 16.12.0 to the latest version or the version you need to setup.

Answer (score 0):

In terminal run the commands to update the react versions
$npm i react@next react-dom@next

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

No need to install react, just do the following command in terminal in Linux/Mac or cmd in Windows:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

my-app - is a optional name, you may name it whatever you want it to.

It would create the updated template for your next project up and ready!

Comment: this does not answer the question. This creates an application, it does not update the existing package.