# How can I upgrade my react-native version 0.58.6 to 0.65 or newer?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am setting up this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/thenishantgiri/Go-social) on my local machine and I am facing issues.
I have to **upgrade the react-native version of a project from 0.58.6 to 0.65 or newer** and also **upgrade react version from 16.12.0 to 17.0.0 or newer** and same goes for **react-navigation**.

Please help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the react-native version of a project from 0.58.6 to 0.65 or newer :

```
npx react-native upgrade
```

(Use npx , npm , yarn etc. which you are using)

ou may specify a React Native version by passing an argument, e.g. to upgrade to 0.61.0-rc.0 run:

```
npx react-native upgrade 0.61.0-rc.0
```

Here you can change version according to your requirement.

If you want to upgrade your packages(navigation) :

```
npx react-native upgrade
```

Sometimes it doesn't work for me so add updated react-navigation manually. Don't worry it doesn't cause any conflict.

For updating **React Version** i suggest you to visit this  :

[Upgrading React version and it's dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49828493/upgrading-react-version-and-its-dependencies-by-reading-package-json)